# Is it possible to receive uploaded files in PHP without storing them on the filesystem?

Tags: php, file-upload

As far as I know, PHP stores all uploaded files in [upload_tmp_dir](http://www.php.net/manual/de/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) (or the systems default tmp dir, if upload_tmp_dir is not set in the php.ini file).

Then the usual method is to move that file to another place using [move_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

My question is: Is there a way to to retrieve the file in a variable? So it does not need to be stored on the file system at any time?

Reasons are, that I don't have to clean up the files afterwards and don't have to care about file system permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$contents = file_get_contents($_FILES['name']['tmp_name']);
```

It is generally safe to leave the temporary file as it is, PHP will take care to delete it at the end of the request (unless PHP crashes hard during your script).

Comment: It seams to be no way arround at least this one place where files need to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably read the temporary file, convert it to Base64 (for example) and store it on a variable..

Comment: There's no need to convert to B64, PHP variables can hold binary data.

Comment: I was suggesting B64 in case he want to show it with CSS for example. I don't know the use he will give to the data.